# How to use BY keyword correctly in FOR EACH

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I want to go through the records in descending order by `Field4`, but when I put in the code `BY mybuffer.Field4 DESCENDING` I get the error

> After "Field4 DESCENDING" not understandable (247) [translated].

```
FOR EACH mybuffer 
    WHERE mybuffer.Field1 = value1
    AND   mybuffer.Field2 = value2
    AND   mybuffer.Field3 >= value3
    BY    mybuffer.Field4 DESCENDING
    USE-INDEX myindex
    NO-LOCK:

    /* do something */
END.
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the statement with error look like? Sounds like a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure that the combination of USE-INDEX and BY is smart. But your problem is likely to be the order of options.

Use in this order:

- USE-INDEX
- NO-LOCK
- BY

Answer (score 1):

The error is the placement of USE-INDEX "After field 4 descending".  Just like the error message says.

The correct syntax is:

```
for each customer no-lock use-index cust-num
  where sales-rep = "BBB"
  by city:

  display customer.

end.
```

FWIW it is unlikely to be a good idea to have both USE-INDEX in a FOR EACH loop and  even less likely to be a good idea to be combining it with BY.  The compiler will probably choose a better index (or indexes plural) if you allow it to.

Comment: Could you please explain (or give a link) why I shouldn't use USE-INDEX (in combination with BY) in a FOR EACH loop? Is there other possibility to iterate through a table "backwards"?

Comment: If you need reverse order you use the DESCENDING keyword.  Ordering is specified with BY -- if that order does not match USE-INDEX then client-side sorting of the result set will occur.  If you specify USE-INDEX then only that single index can be used for selection, whereas complex  queries can often use multiple indexes if the compiler is left to its own decisions.  The compiler is also generally smarter than most programmers so unless you have some very solid proof that you have outsmarted it you should not be in the habit of tossing around USE-INDEX.